# Проблема с циклом счетчика: не срабатывает date_t

Tags: jquery

Есть функция, внутри её

```
 var date_t = 1401355020000;    
 var date = new Date();
 var timer = date_t - date;
```

date_t это время до куда будет считать счетчик, т.е.

```
if(date_t > date){
   //код
}
```

Вот в чем проблема, пока date_t больше date счетчик будет тикать, но надо сделать, когда timer равен нулю или меньше, то мы к date_t прибавляем +2 дня то-есть +259096759.
внутри функции написал

```
  if(timer < 0){
    date_t = date_t + 259096759;
  }
```

Но ничего не срабатывает. Пожалуйста, подскажите в чем проблема?
Если что то вот исходник http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CnIgD

Comment: так вы к таймеру прибавляйте два дня и всё :) date_t от этого увеличится конечно, но таймер то станет <0 и при след шаге оно опять два дня прибавит :)

Comment: Подскажите, как я могу к счетчикунему прибавить +2дня?

Comment: timer+=259096759

Comment: Вам необходимо, чтобы функция get_timer принимала в качестве параметра время, до которого считать. Таким образом, когда timer < 0, вы вызываете эту же функцию, подавая в нее текущее время + 2 дня. Таким образом, получится что-то вроде этого http://jsfiddle.net/dpNQc/1/

Comment: не работает :(

Comment: не хочет работать. likerRr  ваш пример тоже не работает :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то вы странно делаете, если не работает. Да и вообще код не рационально сделан, есть же стандартные функции для работы с датой. Для решения, сразу после переменных делайте проверку и прибавляйте нужное значение:

```
...
var date = new Date();
var date_t = 1401359640000+3300000; 
var timer = date_t - date;

if(timer<=0) timer+=259096759;
...
```